# VB.Net - Use regular expression to identify new lines between double quotes

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

I have the following string value:

```
1A-2A-3A-"Comment line 1
Comment line 2
Comment line A1
Comment line A2"-BREAK1
1B-2B-3B-"Comment line 3
Comment line 4"-BREAK2
1C-2C-3C-4C-BREAK3
1D-2D-3D-4D-BREAK4
```

I want use a regular expression in vb.net that give me the following result:

```
1A-2A-3A-"Comment line 1|Comment line 2|Comment line A1|Comment line A2"-BREAK1
1B-2B-3B-"Comment line 3|Comment line 4"-BREAK2
1C-2C-3C-4C-BREAK3
1D-2D-3D-4D-BREAK4
```

Basically the rule is to remove any new line between double quotes.

Any help will be welcome!

Comment: The basic requirement for regular expressions (and any other type of "small-length-code" approach) is getting a clear pattern. What is the pattern in your inputs? Remove new lines after lines including the word "line"? Also can you please post what you have tried?

Comment: Also your inputs do not respond to any VB.NET-accepted format. Shall we understand that there is an Environment.NewLine after each line in the first code block?

Comment: @varocarbas the pattern is removes newlines when the text it's found between double quotes

Comment: Yes, it was clearer with your second set of examples. In any case, you should have provided it in a VB-acceptable format (and have shown your attempts). Now you have an answerer, explain your conditions to him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the next solution:

```
Dim vInput = <xml>1A-2A-3A-"Comment line 1
Comment line 2
Comment line A1
Comment line A2"-BREAK1
1B-2B-3B-"Comment line 3
Comment line 4"-BREAK2
1C-2C-3C-4C-BREAK3
1D-2D-3D-4D-BREAK4</xml>.Value

Dim vRegExMatch = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(vInput, """[^""\\]*(?:\\.[^""\\]*)*""|'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'")
Dim vSpecialChar As Char = "|" '"†"

For Each vMatch In vRegExMatch
    vInput = vInput.Replace(CStr(vMatch.Value), CStr(vMatch.Value).Replace(vbLf, vSpecialChar))
Next
```

Result:

```
1A-2A-3A-"Comment line 1|Comment line 2|Comment line A1|Comment line A2"-BREAK1
1B-2B-3B-"Comment line 3|Comment line 4"-BREAK2
1C-2C-3C-4C-BREAK3
1D-2D-3D-4D-BREAK4
```

Hope that helps to somebody!